# How do I change the default for the "df" command in unix/linux?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to change a default for the `df` command.

When I type the `df` command, I see the amount of disk free space listed in kilobytes. I want to change the default so that when I type in `df` alone, I will see the disk free space in Megabytes.

I already know that when I type `df -m` or `df -h` I will see it in megabytes, but I strictly just want to type in `df` so that I can see the values in megabytes.

If I can get a step by step on how to make this possible on changing the default for the `df` command to megabytes, I would love that. I was told that command line flags also could affect how this command could work, so I would also like clarification on that as well.

Answer (score 8):

There is a file in your home directory called `.bashrc` which is executed every time you open a new terminal. In nautilus (the default graphical file browser) you will need to press `Ctl+H` to see files that start with a `.`

You can create "aliases" in this file, they will act as commands at the terminal. Edit .bashrc  and add `alias df="df -m"` on its own line, probably best to put this at the top or bottom with a comment above it along the lines of `#I added this line to change the behaviour of df`.

Open a new terminal and `df` will now be `df -m` by default.

N.b. To use `df` normally you must now type `\df`

Answer (score 1):

Like `ls -s`, `df` honors the BLOCKSIZE environmental variable.  Put

```
BLOCKSIZE=1m
export BLOCKSIZE
```

into the `.profile` file in your home directory and when you next login `df` will report disk capacity and availability in megabytes.

If you're using `tcsh` instead of `bash` or `sh` as your shell, put

`setenv BLOCKSIZE 1m`

into `.login` in your home directory.

Comment: Depending on which Unix/Linux, the following variables may perform the same function: DF_BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, and BLOCKSIZE.  The GNU coreutils df defaults to 1K byte blocks, unless POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, in which case it uses 512 byte blocks.